# jQuery function to return HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I want to return HTML and then use it in a conditional if statement in a wider function.

```
function adverts(selector, dfp, index, tempURL) {
$(dfp).each(function(){
    var code = $(this).data("dfpcode");
    var position = $(this).data("adposition");
    if(index == position) {
        $.get(tempURL + "/shortcodes.php?shortcode=" + code, function() {

        }).done(function(content){
            return content;
        });
    }
    else {
        return "";
    }
});
}
```

And I want to use it here

```
var dfpHTML = adverts(selector, ".dfp", i, tempURL).parseHTML();

if(dfpHTML.length > 0) {
    $(div).append(dfpHTML);
}
else {

}
```

but when I run this in my function this is the error I get
`TypeError: adverts(...) is undefined`

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous that you should wait after `done()` callback fired.

Comment: Also the `adverts` function implicitly returns `undefined` and `undefined` doesn't have `parseHTML` method.

Comment: I chuckled a bit when I saw a lot of `undefined` in your comment @undefined.